# Rollback all the migrations in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord, database-migration, rails-migrations

How can I delete / rollback all the migrations that have been run without having to drop and setup the database

```
rake db:rollback
```

goes back just one version. How can I get it to go all the way ?

Comment: You can use `rake db:reset`

Comment: But that internally calls - db:drop and db:setup. I do not want the drop to be called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is :

```
rake db:rollback STEP=10000000
```

Which pretty much means hacking your way back so many steps that the migration   always goes to step 0.
  Another way is:

```
  rake db:migrate VERSION=0
```

More references [here.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/ActiveRecord/Migrations)

Comment: If I want to all the way ? (i.e I dont want to know the number of migrations run)

Comment: I added another option. Does it suit the problem?

Comment: Kinda :) But I do not want to have to type the version.

Comment: rake db:migrate VERSION=0

will get you back at the starting point

Answer (score 0):

You can run `$ rake db:migrate:status`  to see all of your migrations and whether they're in the up or down state.  Go to the very first migration in that list and run:

```
 rake db:rollback VERSION=version_id_shown_by_migrate_status_list_you_just_did
```

Note that if you undo all migrations, all data will be lost when the columns or tables are dropped.  You can then reload the migrations by doing a normal `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Ya, I could do that. Nothing simpler than that. e.g rake db:rollback STEP=-1

Answer (score 0):

To rollback all the migrations use `bin/rake:db reset`.
Pay attention, if a migration can't be rolledback, rake db:reset may fails.

[References here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#resetting-the-database)

Comment: That drops the db (db:drop). I do not want to drop the DB.